# How to return SPECIFIC users from Meteor.users collection based on the current logged in user?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am concerned about Meteor accounts flexibility. I want to return `Meteor.users` collection to the client side based on specific attribute (inside `Meteor.user.profile`) in the current logged in user

For example, a user with HR position can only return the users that are working under him. and the employees working under him will have `employeeHR` attribute.

Now what I want from you guys is to know if the approach I am planning to take is feasible?

And are there better approaches to serve my purpose?

**UPDATE:**

I used the following code to test if I can retrieve the value of `authorityLevel`, and it is successfully printed to the console :

```
Session.set('checkAuthority', Meteor.user().profile.authorityLevel);
console.log(Session.get('checkAuthority'));
```

then, I tried to return users based on their `authorityLevel`, here is the code:

```
if(!Meteor.user().profile.authorityLevel){
            return Meteor.users.find({}, { sort: {createdAt: -1}});
        }
        if(Meteor.user().profile.authorityLevel === "HR") {
            return Meteor.users.find({authorityLevel: "HRemployee"}, { sort: {createdAt: -1}});
        }
```

it doesn't work and I get the following error in the console

```
Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of null
    at Object.employees
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**NOTE:**

I get the same error even when logging in with a user that has the `authorityLevel` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Meteor accounts has plenty of flexibility.

One approach could be to use the alanning:roles package which will allow you define roles, and also groups.

You could define groups to reflect the organisation (eg departments). A HR user, if they have the role to administer, can see users in the group.

Comment: I am trying to implement what I think is faster solution instead of using another package.I updated my question, If you could take a look please

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at `Meteor.user()` before it has been fully published to the client. Do:

```
if( Meteor.user() && !Meteor.user().profile.authorityLevel )
```

to make sure it's all there before you try to read the `profile` key.

If it's any consolation, everyone runs into this issue at some point along their Meteor learning curve.